# Elastic beanstalk: Unhandled exception during build: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I get this error when I deploy my Django app on EB:

```
2014-02-10 11:04:51,037 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 122, in <module>
    worklog.build(detail.metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 117, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 502, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 511, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 216, in build
    changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages, self._auth_config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/apt_tool.py", line 48, in apply
    cache_result = ProcessHelper(['apt-cache', '-q', 'gencaches']).call()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 406, in call
    shell=isinstance(self._cmd, basestring), env=self._env, cwd=self._cwd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

…and I have no idea why and what file or directory it's looking for! Any idea?

ps. I'm using Django 1.6.2 with Python 2.7

This is my app.config inside .ebextensions:

```
packages:
  yum:
    python-devel: []
    libpcap: []
    libpcap-devel: []
    libnet: []
    libnet-devel: []
    pcre: []
    pcre-devel: []
    gcc: []
    gcc-c++: []
    automake: []
    autoconf: []
    libtool: []
    make: []
    libyaml: []
    libyaml-devel: []
    libxml2: []
    libxml2-devel: []
    zlib: []
    zlib-devel: []
    file-devel: []
    postgresql: []
    postgresql-devel: []
    geoip: []
    geoip-devel: []
    graphviz: []
    graphviz-devel: []
  apt:
    binutils: []
    libproj-dev: []
    gdal-bin: []
    python-gdal: []

option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "mysettings"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    NumProcesses: 10
    NumThreads: 1
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem was apt packages declared in config file, despite in its documentation Amazon says it supports apt, that's not true, or at least not for the standard Linux AMI 64but for Python 2.7! That AMI runs Linux Red Hat, which doesn't provide apt, so I have to rely only on yum.
Now my problem is to figure out how to install my dependencies in another manner, since yum repositories in that distribution don't have the libraries I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's trying to deploy to a Ubuntu box and maybe the box you are deploying is not Ubuntu? (Elastic Beanstalk deploys to Amazon Linux images generally)

You can see with in the error that it's trying to run the `apt-cache` command that is only available on Ubuntu:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/apt_tool.py", line 48, in apply
cache_result = ProcessHelper(['apt-cache', '-q', 'gencaches']).call()
```

Comment: the OS it's not ubuntu, it's the default Amazon Linux AMI for python 2.7 64bit, in fact apt command is not installed (I tried it by connecting via SSH to the created EC2 instance)… I'm lost :(

Comment: I saw your other question too. By any chance, do you have `apt` in your `app.config` ?

Comment: I defined some apt package to download (according to the docs it should be a valid definition)… check my edit in the question. Thanks ;)

Comment: Yeah I saw that too. I don't know why that's on the docs. Have you tried removing the `apt` definitions?

Comment: I tried to use yum for some packages I need but I get an error saying that they are not available, instead I get no error by using apt (at least in the settings validation step) ps: I'm gonna delete the other question, since it's becoming difficult to chat in 2 places ;)

Comment: The fact that you get no errors doesn't mean something it's actually getting executed :)

Comment: Did it get fixed then ?